# CSS list item width/height does not work

Tags: css

I tried to make a navigation inline list. You can find it here:  http://www.luukratief-design.nl/dump/parallax/para.html

For some reason it does not display the width and height of the LI. Here is the snippet. What is wrong with this?

```
.navcontainer-top li {
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;<br>
    width: 117px;
    height: 26px;
}


.navcontainer-top li a {
    background: url("../images/nav-button.png") no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 117px;
    height: 26px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.navcontainer-top li a:hover {
    background: url("../images/nav-button-hover.png") no-repeat;
    color: #dedede;
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Declare the `a` element as `display: inline-block` and drop the width and height from the `li` element.

Alternatively, apply a `float: left` to the `li` element and use `display: block` on the `a` element. This is a bit more cross browser compatible, as `display: inline-block` is not supported in Firefox <= 2 for example.

The first method allows you to have a dynamically centered list if you give the `ul` element a width of 100% (so that it spans from left to right edge) and then apply `text-align: center`.

Use `line-height` to control the text's Y-position inside the element.

Answer (score 11):

Inline items cannot have a width. You have to use `display: block` or `display:inline-block`, but the latter is not supported everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, that you're trying to set width to an inline element which I'm not sure is possible. In general Li is block and this would work.

Answer (score 2):

Using width/height on inline elements is not always a good idea.
You can use `display: inline-block` instead

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<br>` from the `.navcontainer-top li` styles.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to fix the item size to fit the background image width.  This worked (at least with Firefox 35) for me :

```
.navcontainer-top li
{
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../images/nav-button.png") no-repeat;
  width: 117px;
  height: 26px;
}
```