# 'Floating Layer' getting caught below HTML table

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I've had a little experience with basic HTML in the past, but I'm still fairly new to .JS and .CSS (sorry).

EDIT: I have also tried to search this site to make sure this question about floating layers getting caught on other items on the page (when they are technically supposed to float over them) has not been asked before; but I haven't found anything yet.

I'm currently trying to create a HTML movie catalogue for an Android Tablet (Galaxy Tab 3) with expanding tables **and my first floating layer**, with many thanks to the advice from other users on this forum (refer my previous question) together with numerous other tutorials I'm reading online.

Thanks for all the advice I've been given so far; I've somewhat cleaned up my previous draft versions, I seem to be on the right track now (I hope!), and my test files have all worked on Android (I'm getting closer, thank god!)

**MY GOAL:**
Now because I will be using frames further down the track, I'm trying to attempt a "floating layer" which grants the user to "jump" to certain parts of the long list with #href id tags, and without having to scroll through 1000+ rows on a 10" tablet.

I've had a look at 'Floating Layer' tutorials, namely this one (of which has been written by Henrik Petersen and is excellent):

```
http://www.echoecho.com/toolfloatinglayer.htm
```

But when I apply the EXACT same script to MY list.html, the floating layer gets stuck to the bottom of my expanding table **and doesn't move**. I cannot see why (beyond my level of experience). I can't see anything wrong with the table code itself.

I've run a console check on my page using Mozilla Firefox and I unfortunately don't understand the errors that is reading out to me. It says "Error in parsing value for "left" and "top"." but doesn't tell me where these errors are occurring for me to fix them.

Can somebody please help? I am so close to getting my final goal!

Here is my index.HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Demo Expandable list</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
floatX=10;
floatY=10;
layerwidth=100;
layerheight=130;
halign="right";
valign="bottom";
delayspeed=3;

// This script is copyright (c) Henrik Petersen, NetKontoret
// Feel free to use this script on your own pages as long as you do not change it.
// It is illegal to distribute the script as part of a tutorial / script archive.
// Updated version available at: http://www.echoecho.com/toolfloatinglayer.htm
// This comment and the 4 lines above may not be removed from the code.

NS6=false;
IE4=(document.all);
if (!IE4) {NS6=(document.getElementById);}
NS4=(document.layers);

function adjust() {
if ((NS4) || (NS6)) {
if (lastX==-1 || delayspeed==0)
{
lastX=window.pageXOffset + floatX;
lastY=window.pageYOffset + floatY;
}
else
{
var dx=Math.abs(window.pageXOffset+floatX-lastX);
var dy=Math.abs(window.pageYOffset+floatY-lastY);
var d=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
var c=Math.round(d/10);
if (window.pageXOffset+floatX>lastX) {lastX=lastX+delayspeed+c;}
if (window.pageXOffset+floatX<lastX) {lastX=lastX-delayspeed-c;}
if (window.pageYOffset+floatY>lastY) {lastY=lastY+delayspeed+c;}
if (window.pageYOffset+floatY<lastY) {lastY=lastY-delayspeed-c;}
}
if (NS4){
document.layers['floatlayer'].pageX = lastX;
document.layers['floatlayer'].pageY = lastY;
}
if (NS6){
document.getElementById('floatlayer').style.left=lastX;
document.getElementById('floatlayer').style.top=lastY;
}
}
else if (IE4){
if (lastX==-1 || delayspeed==0)
{
lastX=document.body.scrollLeft + floatX;
lastY=document.body.scrollTop + floatY;
}
else
{
var dx=Math.abs(document.body.scrollLeft+floatX-lastX);
var dy=Math.abs(document.body.scrollTop+floatY-lastY);
var d=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
var c=Math.round(d/10);
if (document.body.scrollLeft+floatX>lastX) {lastX=lastX+delayspeed+c;}
if (document.body.scrollLeft+floatX<lastX) {lastX=lastX-delayspeed-c;}
if (document.body.scrollTop+floatY>lastY) {lastY=lastY+delayspeed+c;}
if (document.body.scrollTop+floatY<lastY) {lastY=lastY-delayspeed-c;}
}
document.all['floatlayer'].style.posLeft = lastX;
document.all['floatlayer'].style.posTop = lastY;
}
setTimeout('adjust()',50);
}

function define()
{
if ((NS4) || (NS6))
{
if (halign=="left") {floatX=ifloatX};
if (halign=="right") {floatX=window.innerWidth-ifloatX-layerwidth-20};
if (halign=="center") {floatX=Math.round((window.innerWidth-20)/2)-Math.round(layerwidth/2)};
if (valign=="top") {floatY=ifloatY};
if (valign=="bottom") {floatY=window.innerHeight-ifloatY-layerheight};
if (valign=="center") {floatY=Math.round((window.innerHeight-20)/2)-Math.round(layerheight/2)};
}
if (IE4)
{
if (halign=="left") {floatX=ifloatX};
if (halign=="right") {floatX=document.body.offsetWidth-ifloatX-layerwidth-20}
if (halign=="center") {floatX=Math.round((document.body.offsetWidth-20)/2)-Math.round(layerwidth/2)}
if (valign=="top") {floatY=ifloatY};
if (valign=="bottom") {floatY=document.body.offsetHeight-ifloatY-layerheight}
if (valign=="center") {floatY=Math.round((document.body.offsetHeight-20)/2)-Math.round(layerheight/2)}
}
}
//-->
</script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
        </script>

<style type="text/css">
.myTable { background-color:#000000;border-collapse:collapse; }
.myTable th { background-color:#000000;color:white; }
.myTable tr { background:#000000 url(img/back.png) repeat-x scroll top left; }
.myTable td, .myTable th { padding:0.5px;border:1px solid #666666; }
</style>

<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
</style>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black">

<font face="Arial">
<center>
<table class="myTable">
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10" padding:0px;><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td>+</td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Name</a></p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subs?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><a href="" target="_blank">Trailer</a></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr style="color: #FFFFFF;"><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</center>
</font>


<script>
if (NS4) {document.write('<LAYER NAME="floatlayer" LEFT="'+floatX+'" TOP="'+floatY+'">');}
if ((IE4) || (NS6)) {document.write('<div id="floatlayer" style="position:absolute; left:'+floatX+'; top:'+floatY+';">');}
</script>
 <center>
  <font color="white">
    <A HREF="javascript:history.go(0)">RELOAD</A> - <a href="#action">ACTION</a> - <a href="#adventure">ADVENTURE</a> - <a href="#animated">ANIMATED</a> - <a href="#biography">BIOGRAPHY</a> - <a href="#comedy">COMEDY</a> - <a href="#crime">CRIME</a> - <a href="#documentary">DOCUMENTARY</a> - <a href="#drama">DRAMA</a> - <a href="#fantasy">FANTASY</a> - <a href="#foreign">FOREIGN</a>
    <BR><a href="#historical">HISTORICAL</a> - <a href="#horror">HORROR</a> - <a href="#martial_arts">MARTIAL ARTS</a> - <a href="#musical">MUSICAL</a> - <a href="#romance">ROMANCE</a> - <a href="#sci_fi">SCI FI</a> - <a href="#stand_up">STAND UP COMEDY</a> - <a href="#superhero">SUPERHERO</a> - <a href="#thriller">THRILLER</a> - <a href="#war">WAR</a> - <a href="#western">WESTERN</a>
  </font>
 </center>

<script>
if (NS4)
{
document.write('</LAYER>');
}
if ((IE4) || (NS6))
{
document.write('</DIV>');
}
ifloatX=floatX;
ifloatY=floatY;
define();
window.onresize=define;
lastX=-1;
lastY=-1;
adjust();
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my style.CSS file:

```
table{ width: 98%; }
tr {border: 1px solid #666666;}

.scroll-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /*making the scroll have momentum on mobile devices
    http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements
    */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
/*hiding the scrollbar*/
.scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
 }


a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 0em;
}
```

And here is my scripts.JS file:

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=10]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
            $target.closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").html("+");
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
            if ($target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html() == "+")
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("-");
            else
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("+");                
        }                    
    });
});
```

Apologies if it's still a little messy, I'm trying to learn as much as I can from this and improve, and I've been trying for a week now. I don't take any classes on this, so it's all self-taught and backwards-engineered from people that know a LOT more than I do.

A little info on me: I'm actually an architectural draftsman by trade, I draft plans for construction using AutoCAD; so ANY computer programming for me is unknown. I do think that HTML is beautiful, however.

This time I've omitted all photographs to avoid confusion. I'm just trying to get the code to work before I start populating all the rows with useful information relevant to me.

Many thanks in advance, and kudos to whomever can read my mess and spot the flaw!

Comment: I am still confused, what are you trying to achieve. Please correct me if I am wrong. You want a floating menu of movie category?

Comment: Yes, just a small rectangular box with some hyperlinks (RELOAD, ACTION, etc) floating over the entire page. But for some reason the floating menu gets caught on the existing table and doesn't move.

Comment: Why are u using any plugin, you can achieve this by css

Comment: you can refer this http://jsbin.com/dopugehaci/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that! The plug-in moved dynamically with the page and looked cool, but didn't work. I'll work on this later and if it works I'll close this topic. Thank you

Comment: If you can explain complete requirement with details, I can help you to build that script :)

Comment: Ok I've made 2x screenshots on photoshop trying to demonstrate floating layer, I hope you can access it: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DD86D796C03ED2B0!607&authkey=!AI56DLbQ6Kpjjyo&ithint=album%2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a rough layout, check this and let me know what else you want in this.

http://jsbin.com/goyepuhifo/1/edit

Comment: One last question @prah, If I populate all these columns <LI> points with text, I get rows with columns with varying widths... Is there any way to have preset widths, or at least a command that forces all columns to be the same width?

Comment: For example, the plus/minus column can be 5-10px, the first column be the name and be 60-70px, the second column is the year and this only needs to be 40px, and so on... I really appreciate your help, @PRAH

Comment: can you please illustrate with image or example

Comment: Sorry for my late reply @Prah, went out with friends to a pub last night and got back pretty late, did some experimentation and solved my own problem. I did some research and discovered that you can't actually specify <li> widths, but some forum some people had some alternate ideas. I didn't really understand the alternate idea, so I created my own through trial and error.

Here is the forum thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295311/css-list-item-width-height-does-not-work

Comment: So what I did was put a <span> inside the <li> command (because I didn't want to lose the <li> command. Ended up looking like this:

<li><span>link 1</span></li>

I then specified the <span> with with a <style> command:

<style type="text/css">
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
</style>

Comment: This worked a treat, (kept widths uniform), but then I realized that I needed some other <li> columns at HALF this width, so I took a guess and wrote the following <style> command:

<style type="text/css">
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
span2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
span3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
</style>

Comment: I think added these <spans> of varying widths to groups you gave me:

    <div class="movie">
      <div class="short-info">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      <li><span>link1</span></li>
      <li>link2</li>
      <li><span2>link3</span2></li>
      <li>link4</li>
      <li>link5</li>
      <li>link6</li>
      <li>link7</li>
      <li><span2>link8</span2></li>
      <li><span3>link9</span3></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     </div>

This gave me pre-set column widths! Perfect!

Comment: I realize that <span3></span3> is probably a disgusting non-standard tactic invented by a n00b, but hey, it works on my laptop, and it works on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 running Android and Google Chrome which is most important (for me). I'm not going to make this thing commercial, so I honestly don't really mind if this command doesn't work on Firefox versions below version 2, or IE, or Netscape, or whatever. It works NOW and last night I was kicking some awesome goals with this! :-)

Comment: So please don't worry about this question. Your feedback would be nice, however. I'm a total n00b at this and yes I pulled the <span2></span2> and <span3></span3> thing totally out of nothing.

I do have another question, however.

Comment: I'm going to have a lot of rows, of movies and TV shows. Because of this, I've looked into having a search bar located in another floating layer in the html file. I have so far inserted the search bar and customized the shape, colours, everything... It looks good! But I'm having problems with getting the code of the search bar to look within THIS document. Is there anyway I can have a search bar search all the <li> title fields and automatically highlight the <li> search result? It doesn't have to automatically expand the found column, (would be nice, but not needed?).

Comment: Do you know how to program a search bar to search for (and scroll to) whatever film you type?

I'm happy to send you what I have so far in a ZIP file, if you like? I've just hit a road block.

Comment: Sure, I would happy to help. can you create your latest code to jsbin or jsfiddle. I will try to create a piece of code for search to highlight

Comment: thank you so much for the offer, but was playing around with it on the Samsung Galaxy Tab (trying to get all the margins perfect) and discovered that the Google Chrome app already has a very handy hidden FIND feature, so at this point it might not be needed. Thank you so much again! It's amazing getting good help from good people on the internet!