# Javascript setting width for <li> tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Setting width for `<li>` tags not working. Width is changing based on content for `<li>` tag below is the html code

Without using display: block/table/inline-block;

```html
  

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
    padding: 0px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
}

.menu li  {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
    padding: 10px 50px 0px 0px;
       border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>Java Script</li>
  <li>Java Script CSS</li>
 </ul>  
<ul class="menu">
  <li style="width:80%">Script</li>
  <li>width changed based on content </li>
 </ul> 

</body>
</html>
```

How to make it as fixed length for li tags?

here is the working jsfiddle of above code...
[Above working code](https://jsfiddle.net/rh8my99w/)

Comment: Well first of all, both your `ul`s have the same ID. IDs are meant to be unique. Use classes instead or two different IDs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295311/css-list-item-width-height-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
   background-color: black;
    color: red;
    padding: 10px 50px 0px 0px;
       border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>Java Script</li>
  <li>Java Script CSS</li>
 </ul>  
<ul id="menu">
  <li style="width:80%">Script</li>
  <li>width changed based on content </li>
 </ul> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't use  display: block/table/inline-block; need to use only display: inline;