# span tag inside li with link is moving on hover

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following html. When I hover on the last `li`, a border should generate. When I hover on the last `li`, other li's are moving.

I have gone through these 2 questions.

1. [list item width height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295311/css-list-item-width-height-does-not-work)
2. [fixed with span inside li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257505/css-fixed-width-in-a-span)

I can't able to stop moving the element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu_right">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text 2</a></li>
    <li class="your_space"><a href="#"><span>Text3</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Kindly check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nsh9gzy/).

It maybe a simple issue. But I can't able to find a solution to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a transparent `border` on all the other `<li>` to make it good.

```
ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cu4bL3s/**

Answer (score 2):

Please add `border: 2px solid transparent;` to all the li

```css
.menu_right {
  float: right;
}
ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
li.your_space {
  width: 100px;
}
li.your_space:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
li.your_space a>span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_right">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Text 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="your_space"><a href="#"><span>Text3</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

another solution

Add `padding:2px;` to all li and on hover remove padding of the hovered li and add border to it
Add this CSS

```
.menu_right{
  float:right;
}
ul.menu li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:2px;
}
ul.menu li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
li.your_space{
  width:100px;
}
li.your_space:hover{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding:0;
}
li.your_space a>span{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explaining: 
This is because you are setting a `border` property on hover, which causes the `li` to add the border property to its `height` / `width`.

You need to set `transparent` borders on all your `li` independent on they state, so when you hover any `li` you won't be adding a border but changing its color.

```
ul.menu li {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

course blocks will move, you add a 2 pixel border (left + right = 4px). As an alternative I can propose "[outline](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)"

```
li.your_space:hover{
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```